# DB2 MERGE does not INSERTwhen NOT MATCHED

Tags: sql, merge, db2

My Statement:

```
MERGE INTO tblshoppingcart AS target USING 
(SELECT * FROM tblshoppingcart 
WHERE session_id = 'f7f2eb03-5ca5-4a85-b83e-70f197c087ae ' AND primlink = '19830625000054' AND store = 17 AND catalog = 'SS3' AND quantity = 35 AND item_type = 0) AS source 
ON target.primlink = source.primlink AND 
target.session_id = source.session_id AND target.item_type = source.item_type 
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
        INSERT VALUES ( 'f7f2eb03-5ca5-4a85-b83e-70f197c087ae', '19830625000054', 17, 'SS3', 'PAS', 35, 5, '', 0 ) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET quantity = 15
```

When matched the UPDATE works fine

When NOT MATCHED the INSERT doesn't throw an error but doesn't insert anything either.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN to:

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
```

Comment: TARGET being a SQL keyword, you might want to change the alias target to T or something that does not conflict with keywords.

Comment: Thanks, for the repsonses I found the issue to be I was passing hardcoded values but when I used the source/target names it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, for the repsonses I found the issue to be I was passing hardcoded values but when I used the source/target names it worked.

So instead of `INSERT VALUES ( 'f7f2eb03-5ca5-4a85-b83e-70f197c087ae'`

I do `INSERT VALUES ( target.session`